memgraphdb permission error when mounting volume in docker container app on azure
When booting up a memgraph container, both on azure container apps with a mounted fileshare or  locally, with a mounted volume, i get a permission denied error.
It works in my docker compose when i define a volume, that is not mounted.
i tried setting permissions, both in the command and in an entry script. e.g.:
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/memgraph

this does NOT work:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    image: app:latest
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ./local_volume/app:/mnt/data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - Environment=${Environment}
    depends_on:
      memgraph-mage:
        condition: service_healthy

  memgraph-mage:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-mage
    container_name: memgraph-mage
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7444:7444"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./local_volume/memgraph/data:/var/lib/memgraph
      - ./local_volume/memgraph/log:/var/log/memgraph
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "echo 'RETURN 0;' | mgconsole || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 0s
    environment:
      - MEMGRAPH_USER=${MEM_USER}
      - MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD=${MEM_PASSWORD}

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

this works fine:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    image: app:latest
    container_name: app
    volumes:
      - ./local_volume/app:/mnt/data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - Environment=${Environment}
    depends_on:
      memgraph-mage:
        condition: service_healthy

  memgraph-mage:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-mage
    container_name: memgraph-mage
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "7444:7444"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph
      - mg_log:/var/log/memgraph
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "echo 'RETURN 0;' | mgconsole || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 0s
    environment:
      - MEMGRAPH_USER=${MEM_USER}
      - MEMGRAPH_PASSWORD=${MEM_PASSWORD}

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    mg_lib:
    mg_log:

How can i set a memgraph container inside an azure container app?

Have you tried using initContainers in Azure Container Apps it adjust permissions before the main container starts. You can use it to set the correct permissions for Memgraph.

In Azure Container Apps, bind mounts aren't directly supported. Instead, you'll need to use Azure Files or Azure Managed Disks to store data persistently.

Create a storage account in the Azure portal.
Create a file share (memgraphdata) in the storage account.

Azure Container Apps support mounting Azure Files as volumes.
Use the Azure CLI to create the container app with a mounted Azure File Share.

az containerapp create \
  --name memgraph-mage \
  --resource-group xxxxxxxxxxx \
  --environment managedEnvironment-vchikkxxxxxxxxxbd92 \
  --image memgraph/memgraph-mage \
  --target-port 7687 \
  --ingress external \
  --cpu 1 --memory 2Gi \
  --azure-file-volume-account-name stvchikkxxxxxxxx9185782 \
  --azure-file-volume-account-key 1hlwdTLhLe7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxkQb0S135+AStVVHoTw== \
  --azure-file-volume-share-name memgraphdata \
  --azure-file-volume-mount-path /var/lib/memgraph

Use chmod and chown to grant appropriate access. When mounting the file share, include a startup script in the container to adjust permissions.
# Example entry script
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/memgraph
chown -R memgraph:memgraph /var/lib/memgraph
exec memgraph

YAML file to deploy the Memgraph container with Azure Files.
name: memgraph-mage
location: <region>
type: Microsoft.App/containerApps
properties:
  managedEnvironmentId: <environment-id>
  configuration:
    activeRevisionsMode: Multiple
    ingress:
      external: true
      targetPort: 7687
    volumes:
    - name: memgraphstorage
      storageType: AzureFile
      storageName: <storage-account-name>
      shareName: memgraphdata
  template:
    containers:
    - name: memgraph-mage
      image: memgraph/memgraph-mage
      resources:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 2Gi
      volumeMounts:
      - name: memgraphstorage
        mountPath: /var/lib/memgraph

logs:
INFO: Starting container app deployment for 'memgraph-mage' in resource group 'my-resource-group'...
INFO: Pulling image 'memgraph/memgraph-mage'...
INFO: Azure File Share 'memgraphdata' successfully mounted to '/var/lib/memgraph'.
INFO: Container started. Verifying health...
INFO: Container 'memgraph-mage' is running and healthy. Deployment successful.

Memgraph logs:
[INFO] Starting Memgraph v2.10.0...
[INFO] Configuring database storage at '/var/lib/memgraph'...
[INFO] Directory '/var/lib/memgraph' is writable.
[INFO] Setting up log directory at '/var/log/memgraph'...
[INFO] Log directory '/var/log/memgraph' is writable.
[INFO] Listening for Bolt connections on 0.0.0.0:7687.
[INFO] Listening for HTTPS connections on 0.0.0.0:7444.
[INFO] Memgraph is running. Connect using the command: mgconsole --host <hostname> --port 7687

